# How to configure sql database c# windows form application

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am currently writing a windows form application in c#.
I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management 2008 R2 to store my data in the database.
My application work fine when I am using my own laptop because my server name in database is set to localhost.
However, this program will not work if I am trying on other people's laptop (cannot connect to my database).
I want to write a configure file for this program so that the user can access my windows form application anywhere.
I am sure sure how to get it done.
My servername is localhost and this is my SQL connection string in my Form1.cs. Help and example for reference will be appreciated, thanks

```
myConn = new SqlConnection("Server = localhost; Initial Catalog= dbName; Trusted_Connection = True");
```

**Updated** (I don't have password to connect)

```
   <connsectionStrings>
     <add name="myConn" connectionString="Data Source=PC6\SA;Initial Catalog=dbName;"/>       
 </connsectionStrings>


<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />


</startup>
```

Comment: if u can ping ur system from other system then u can connect to the database by changing `localhost` to your ipaddress or sql server name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

**SQL Server Authentication**

```
<add name="myConn" connectionString="Data Source=PC6\SA;Initial Catalog=dbName;User ID=sa;Password=sa123"/>
```

**Windows Authentication**

```
<add name="myConn" connectionString="Data Source=PC6\SA;Initial Catalog=dbName; />
```

Comment: Hi Denish, thank you for your quick reply. Just wondering am I adding is this code in the App.config file, and what is PC6\SA ? :/

Comment: yes.In the `config`.`PC6/SA` would become your ipaddress or `sql` instance name as @Sachu mentioned.

Comment: @Amit, thank you for your respond. I will give it a try :)

Comment: I tried this code, somehow I get the `An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in System.Data.dll`